# Two labels overlap each other when using the Radio Button Listener

Tags: java, swing, awt

I made a simple program where there are two radio buttons each with an action listener.
After pressing first button, a label is printed and the same thing happens with the other.
The problem is that both the labels overlap after pressing first and second button.

Edit-The previous label must be removed and then new label must be on the screen.
ex-

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class ckbxdm{
    JFrame frame;
    JRadioButton r1,r2;
    ButtonGroup grp;
    JLabel l1,l2;

    void box(){
        frame=new JFrame("Hello");
        r1=new JRadioButton("Login");
        r2=new JRadioButton("Signup");
        grp=new ButtonGroup();
        grp.add(r1);
        grp.add(r2);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.getContentPane().add(r1);
        frame.getContentPane().add(r2);
        r1.setBounds(100,120,100,20);
        r2.setBounds(200,120,100,20);
        frame.setBounds(100,100,500,500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        r1.addActionListener(new listener1());
        r2.addActionListener(new listener2());
    }
    class listener1 implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
            frame.getContentPane().repaint();
            frame.getContentPane().revalidate();
            l1=new JLabel("Login area");
            frame.getContentPane().add(l1);
            l1.setBounds(100,200,100,20);
        }
    }
    class listener2 implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
            frame.getContentPane().repaint();
            frame.getContentPane().revalidate();
            l2=new JLabel("Signup area");
            frame.getContentPane().add(l2);
            l2.setBounds(100,200,100,20);
        }
    }
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie){
        frame.repaint();
    }
}
public class CheckboxDemo{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        ckbxdm obj=new ckbxdm();
        obj.box();
    }
}
```

Comment: Be very careful when you add a `new` action listener to a component. If you were to call the `box()` method multiple times, you would be adding each time a `new` listener, which could create problems for you. Instead, it might be better to create a new instance of a given listener in the constructor and add the instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the answer provided above, if you want to hide the other label, you can set its visibility to `false` and repaint the parent component. You can learn more [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917365/hide-a-button-from-layout-in-java-swing). Note that calling the revalidate method here is unnecessary since you are not removing any component from the hierarchy.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class ckbxdm{
    JFrame frame;
    JRadioButton r1,r2;
    ButtonGroup grp;
    JLabel l1,l2;

    void box(){
        frame=new JFrame("Hello");
        r1=new JRadioButton("Login");
        r2=new JRadioButton("Signup");
        grp=new ButtonGroup();
        grp.add(r1);
        grp.add(r2);

        l1=new JLabel("Login area");
        l1.setBounds(100,200,100,20);
        l1.setVisible(false);
        frame.getContentPane().add(l1);

        l2=new JLabel("Signup area");
        l2.setBounds(100,200,100,20);
        l2.setVisible(false);
        frame.getContentPane().add(l2);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.getContentPane().add(r1);
        frame.getContentPane().add(r2);
        r1.setBounds(100,120,100,20);
        r2.setBounds(200,120,100,20);
        frame.setBounds(100,100,500,500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        r1.addActionListener(new listener1());
        r2.addActionListener(new listener2());
    }
    class listener1 implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
            l2.setVisible(false);
            l1.setVisible(true);
            frame.getContentPane().repaint();

        }
    }
    class listener2 implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
            l1.setVisible(false);
            l2.setVisible(true);
            frame.getContentPane().repaint();
        }
    }
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie){
        frame.repaint();
    }
}
public class CheckboxDemo{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        ckbxdm obj=new ckbxdm();
        obj.box();
    }
}
```

Comment: above program is not working...i think that it is because of the reason that the l2 label is not added so we can not set the visibility false..in the same manner l1 is not added. please there must be different ways.

Comment: oh..sorry..it was my mistake...yes it is working...great

Answer (score 0):

try to change ur "sign up position" in X-Ycooridantes direction, let say change following line of code `l2.setBounds(100,200,100,20);`

to

```
l2.setBounds(200,200,100,20);
```

and the same way for `l1` change it to `l1.setBounds(50,200,100,20);`
, it will definitely work

Comment: thanks for replying...but i need to remove the previous label.ie. each time the user clicks on the button,he will not get the previous label.i think repaint() method would help but i tried but not working.