# Buttons not turning invisible when setVisible is set to false

Tags: java, swing, button, graphics, jbutton

I want to make my code turn off (make invisible) some buttons for a bit so I can flash a sequence of colors. Note I am new to java. Don't bother reading each individual if-else

```java
 public void runPattern() //shows the pattern of colors
      {
            System.out.println("runPatternStart");
            SimonSaysPanel.invisible();
            repaint();
         for(int j = 0; j < SimonSaysPanel.maxCount; j++)
         {
            if(array[j] == 1)
            {
                    System.out.println("runPattern1");
                    myBuffer.setColor(new Color(60, 255, 0));
                    myBuffer.fillRect(0, 0, 150, 150);
                    repaint();
                    timeDelay(2000);
                    myBuffer.setColor(new Color(36, 185, 20));
                    myBuffer.fillRect(0, 0, 150, 150);
                    repaint();
            }
            else if(array[j] == 2)
            {
                    System.out.println("runPattern2");
               myBuffer.setColor(new Color(255, 255, 0));
               myBuffer.fillRect(0, 150, 150, 150);
                    repaint();
                    timeDelay(2000);
               myBuffer.setColor(new Color(204, 200, 16));
               myBuffer.fillRect(0, 150, 150, 150);
                    repaint();
            }
            else if(array[j] == 3)
            {
                    System.out.println("runPattern3");
               myBuffer.setColor(Color.RED);
               myBuffer.fillRect(150, 0, 150, 150);
                    repaint();
                    timeDelay(2000);
               myBuffer.setColor(new Color(209, 20, 20));
               myBuffer.fillRect(150, 0, 150, 150);
                    repaint();
            }
            else if(array[j] == 4)
            {
                    System.out.println("runPattern4");
               myBuffer.setColor(Color.BLUE);
               myBuffer.fillRect(150, 150, 150, 150);
                    repaint();
                    timeDelay(2000);
               myBuffer.setColor(new Color(31, 97, 183));
               myBuffer.fillRect(150, 150, 150, 150); 
                    repaint();

            }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("runPatternError");
                }

         }
         SimonSaysPanel.visible(); 
            repaint();
      }
```

Is where I am calling the invisible method and the invisible and visible methods just look like this:

```java
public static void invisible()
        {
            System.out.println("invisible");
            button1.setEnabled(false);
            button2.setEnabled(false);
            button3.setEnabled(false);
            button4.setEnabled(false); 
        }
        public static void visible()
        {
            System.out.println("visible");
            button1.setEnabled(true);
            button2.setEnabled(true);
            button3.setEnabled(true);
            button4.setEnabled(true); 
        }
```

I have tried setEnabled, setVisible and setOpaque and I don't think any of them work. I think this is the right way to call the method and the output prints "visible" and "invisible" so I don't know what's wrong. I assume the visible and invisible methods are done correctly.

Comment: What's exactly your problem? That your function invisible doesn't hide the buttons? Because to hide the buttons is not the task of `setEnabled(false)`, this function only disable the button, you can't click it... To set a componenet invisible just call `setVisible(false)` and repaint

Comment: @0x1C1B Yeah I'll change the wording. It was originall setVisible but that doesn't seem to work either as I said in the post.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can understand your problem and provide a solution. BTW: to make a button (or any othe component) invisible you need to call `button1.setVisible(true/false);`

Comment: Why are your functions visible/invisible static? How do you pack your buttons to the panel? I found this example [Hide a button from Layout in Java Swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917365/hide-a-button-from-layout-in-java-swing#1917462), it seems to work...

Comment: If the code is executed and you change the property of the component that has been added to the frame, then the code will work. If it doesn't work I suspect you have multiple instance of the component. Why are you methods static? This indicates improper design of your class which may be the cause of your problem. Without a proper [mcve] we can't guess what you are really doing.  So start with a frame with 3 buttons. The first two buttons ("Hide" and "Show") will simply have an ActionListener to hide/show the 3rd button. Get this working first then fix your real code.

Answer (score 0):

Use setOpaque() along with setEnable().